# How to import XML file with varying number of nodes and child nodes into DataTable in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, datatable

I have the following XML file that I need to import into a DataTable in C#:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DATA>
    <SystemID>
        <Information>
        </Information>
    </SystemID>
    <Measurement_Data>
        <Channel_01>
            <Parameter_1 Attribute1="double number" Attribute2="string" Attribute3="double number" Attribute4="string" />
            <Parameter_2 Attribute1="double number" Attribute2="string" Attribute3="double number" Attribute4="string" />
            <Parameter_3 Attribute1="double number" Attribute2="string" Attribute3="double number" Attribute4="string" />
            .
            .
            .
            <Parameter_N Attribute1="double number" Attribute2="string" Attribute3="double number" Attribute4="string" />
        </Channel_01>
        <Channel_02>
            <Parameter_A Attribute1="double number" Attribute2="string" Attribute3="double number" Attribute4="string" />
            <Parameter_B Attribute1="double number" Attribute2="string" Attribute3="double number" Attribute4="string" />
            <Parameter_C Attribute1="double number" Attribute2="string" Attribute3="double number" Attribute4="string" />
            .
            .
            .
            <Parameter_N Attribute1="double number" Attribute2="string" Attribute3="double number" Attribute4="string" />
        </Channel_02>
        .
        .
        .
        <Channel_Z>
            <Parameter_1A Attribute1="double number" Attribute2="string" Attribute3="double number" Attribute4="string" />
            <Parameter_2A Attribute1="double number" Atribute2="string" Attribute3="double number" Attribute4="string" />
            <Parameter_3A Attribute1="double number" Atribute2="string" Attribute3="double number" Attribute4="string" />
            .
            .
            .
            <Parameter_3N Attribute1="double number" Attribute2="string" Attribute3="double number" Attribute4="string" />
        </Channel_Z>
    </Measurement_Data>
</DATA>
```

Here are the boundary conditions in the file:

1. The number of total Channels varies depending on the imported file.
2. The number of Parameters in each Channel varies (both in name and total count).
3. The Parameters for each Channel are not necessarily the same.
4. Each Parameter has exactly the same 4 attributes: 2 are numbers and 2 are strings.

I am able to load the XML document with XmlDocument and create a list of all elements with XElement and separately I am able to generate a DataTable for a single Parameter across multiple channels but I don't know how to piece everything together.

Here is my code for generating DataTable for a single Parameter across multiple channels (note that I don't know how to add the Channel information to DataTable yet):

```
private void OpenButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable values = new DataTable();

    values.Columns.Add("Parameter");
    values.Columns.Add("Attribute1");
    values.Columns.Add("Attribute2");
    values.Columns.Add("Attribute3");
    values.Columns.Add("Attribute4");

    string filePath = @"C:/Users/.../test.xml";

    List<string> parameter = new List<string>();
    List<double> attribute1Values = new List<double>();
    List<string> attribute2Values = new List<string>();
    List<double> attribute3Values = new List<double>();
    List<string> attribute4Values = new List<string>();

    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(filePath);

    XmlNodeList elemList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Parameter_1");
    string param = "Parameter_1";

    for (int i = 0; i < elemList.Count; i++)
    {
        parameter.Add(param);
        attribute1Values.Add(Double.Parse(elemList[i].Attributes["Attribute1"].Value));
        attribute2Values.Add(elemList[i].Attributes["Attribute2"].Value);
        attribute3Values.Add(Double.Parse(elemList[i].Attributes["Attribute3"].Value));
        attribute4Values.Add(elemList[i].Attributes["Attribute4"].Value);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < attribute1Values.Count;i++ )
    {
        var row = values.NewRow();
        row["Parameter"] = parameter[i];
        row["Attribute1"] = attribute1Values[i];
        row["Attribute2"] = attribute2Values[i];
        row["Attribute3"] = attribute3Values[i];
        row["Attribute4"] = attribute4Values[i];
        values.Rows.Add(row);
    }
    dataGridView1.DataSource = values;
}
```

Comment: Mmm, what's this? Why `<Measurement_Data>` does not simply contain `<Channel>` elements, that contains only *n* number of `<Parameter>`s ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
private void OpenButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable values = new DataTable();

    values.Columns.Add("Channel");
    values.Columns.Add("Parameter");
    values.Columns.Add("Attribute1");
    values.Columns.Add("Attribute2");
    values.Columns.Add("Attribute3");
    values.Columns.Add("Attribute4");

    string filePath = @"C:/Users/.../test.xml";
    XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(filePath);

    var channels = from channel in xDoc.Descendants("Measurement_Data").Elements()
                   select new
                   {
                       ChannelName = channel.Name,
                       Parameters = channel.Elements().Select(a => new
                       {
                           ParameterName = a.Name,
                           Attribute1 = a.Attribute("Attribute1").Value,
                           Attribute2 = a.Attribute("Attribute2").Value,
                           Attribute3 = a.Attribute("Attribute3").Value,
                           Attribute4 = a.Attribute("Attribute4").Value
                       })

                   };

    foreach (var channel in channels)
    {
        foreach (var element in channel.Parameters)
        {
            DataRow row = values.NewRow();

            row["Channel"] = channel.ChannelName;
            row["Parameter"] = element.ParameterName;
            // If attributes are not numbers, parsing will generate error.
            row["Attribute1"] = Double.Parse(element.Attribute1);
            row["Attribute2"] = element.Attribute2;
            row["Attribute3"] = Double.Parse(element.Attribute3);
            row["Attribute4"] = element.Attribute4;

            values.Rows.Add(row);
        }
    }
    dataGridView1.DataSource = values;
}
```

I tested it with the following XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DATA>
    <SystemID>
        <Information>
        </Information>
    </SystemID>
    <Measurement_Data>
        <Channel_01>
            <Parameter_1 Attribute1="123" Attribute2="string" Attribute3="456" Attribute4="string" />
            <Parameter_2 Attribute1="123" Attribute2="string" Attribute3="456" Attribute4="string" />
            <Parameter_3 Attribute1="123" Attribute2="string" Attribute3="456" Attribute4="string" />
            <Parameter_N Attribute1="123" Attribute2="string" Attribute3="456" Attribute4="string" />
        </Channel_01>
        <Channel_02>
            <Parameter_A Attribute1="123" Attribute2="string" Attribute3="456" Attribute4="string" />
            <Parameter_B Attribute1="123" Attribute2="string" Attribute3="456" Attribute4="string" />
            <Parameter_C Attribute1="123" Attribute2="string" Attribute3="456" Attribute4="string" />
            <Parameter_N Attribute1="123" Attribute2="string" Attribute3="456" Attribute4="string" />
        </Channel_02>
        <Channel_Z>
            <Parameter_2A Attribute1="123" Attribute2="string" Attribute3="456" Attribute4="string" />
            <Parameter_3A Attribute1="123" Attribute2="string" Attribute3="456" Attribute4="string" />
            <Parameter_1A Attribute1="123" Attribute2="string" Attribute3="456" Attribute4="string" />
            <Parameter_3N Attribute1="123" Attribute2="string" Attribute3="456" Attribute4="string" />
        </Channel_Z>
    </Measurement_Data>
</DATA>
```